# Issues with UI Thread and button behavior in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Firstly, I am new to Android (mainly a C# and Python dev).  Early last year my company asked me to make an app on Handheld Android Scanner.

After researching various methods, I got one created and working (scanned a barcode, hit our API, and displayed the results).

So now I have been tasked to create a different application for our warehouse that is similar in style but has some slightly different behavior.

The catch now, is it hits a different API, gets the results, and based on the results, displays a button that will run a post call against the API to update a flag in the data.

Here is the MainActivity.kt file text:

```
package com.classicoptical.binning

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.device.ScanDevice
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import com.classicoptical.binning.api.ApiRequest
import com.classicoptical.binning.api.BASE_URL
import com.classicoptical.binning.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.HttpException
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.io.IOException

private const val SCAN_ACTION = "scan.rcv.message"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var sm: ScanDevice
    private lateinit var barcodeStr: String
    private lateinit var job: String

    private var mScanReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            binding.tvWaiting.text = "Getting info..."
            val barocode = intent.getByteArrayExtra("barocode")
            val barocodelen = intent.getIntExtra("length", 0)
            val temp = intent.getByteExtra("barcodeType", 0.toByte())
            val aimid = intent.getByteArrayExtra("aimid")
            barcodeStr = String(barocode!!, 0, barocodelen)

            makeApiRequest(barcodeStr)
            sm.stopScan()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //supportActionBar?.hide()

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        sm = ScanDevice()
        sm.setOutScanMode(0)
    }

    public fun runMoveCommand() {
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiRequest::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response = api.moveBinLocation(job)
                Log.d("Main", "success: ${response.success}")
                binding.tvUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                if (response.success == false) {
                    binding.tvUpdate.text = "Error"
                } else {
                    binding.tvUpdate.text = "Moved!!"
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("Main", "IOException: You may not have internet connection - ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.e("Main", "HttpException: unexpected response - ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("Main", "Error: ${e.message}")
            }
        }

    }

    private fun makeApiRequest(scanned_opc: String) {
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiRequest::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response = api.getBinLocation(scanned_opc)
                Log.d("Main", "item_no: ${response.jobID}")
                if (response.jobID == null) {
                    binding.tvWaiting.textSize = 18f
                    binding.tvWaiting.text = "JobID Not recognized.  Try again."
                    binding.tvBinLocation.text = "BAD"
                } else {
                    job = scanned_opc
                    binding.tvWaiting.text = "${response.jobID}"
                    binding.tvBinLocation.text = "${response.binLocation}"
                    if (response.moveOldBinID == 0) {
                        binding.btnMove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        binding.tvMoveLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        binding.btnMove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        binding.tvMoveLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        binding.tvUpdate.text = "${response.moveOldBinLocation}";
                        binding.tvMoveLocation.text = "${response.moveOldBinLocation}";
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("Main", "IOException: You may not have internet connection - ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.e("Main", "HttpException: unexpected response - ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("Main", "Error: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (sm != null) {
            sm.stopScan()
        }
        unregisterReceiver(mScanReceiver)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (sm != null) {
            sm.openScan()
            sm.outScanMode = 0
        }
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(SCAN_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(mScanReceiver, filter)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (sm != null) {
            sm.closeScan()
            sm.stopScan()
            sm.scanLaserMode = 8
        }
    }
}
```

Now firstly, updating the TextViews always works!

In the makeAPIRequest function, If moveOldBinID is 0, binding.btnMove.setVisibility(View.GONE) runs, and the button disappears.  However, when the next line runs (setVisiblity for tvMoveLocation) I get

> Error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Also, if I scan another item where moveOldBinID have a value,
`binding.btnMove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
doesn't do anything, and it doesn't generate the original thread error.  (This also happens if I use View.INVISIBLE as well as View.GONE)

When I've tried to test the button, the app shuts down, so I'm assuming I'm not doing something right with the button.

The button setup in activity_main.xml is

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_move"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_bin_location"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:onClick="runMoveCommand" />
```

I've tried wrapping the else portion of `if (response.jobID == null) {` to use

```
            } else {
                job = scanned_opc
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       binding.tvWaiting.text = "${response.jobID}"
                       binding.tvBinLocation.text = "${response.binLocation}"
                       if (response.moveOldBinID == 0) {
                           binding.btnMove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           binding.tvMoveLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       } else {
                           binding.btnMove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           binding.tvMoveLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           binding.tvUpdate.text = "${response.moveOldBinLocation}";
                           binding.tvMoveLocation.text = "${response.moveOldBinLocation}";
                       }
                   }
                });
            }
```

It gives me Expecting an expression for Runnable(), and it gives me an unresolved reference for new.

So any advice or corrections would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is trying to update the UI in the background thread, which is the `Dispatchers.IO` in this case.

You can learn more about it in this link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#dispatchers-and-threads.

The solution is to use `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {}`. It will launch the coroutine in the Main thread so you can freely update your UI components. Wrap the API calls with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` like this, so it will execute the API call in the background thread.

```kotlin
val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { api.exampleCall(job) }
```

Full code:

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch {
    try {
        val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { api.moveBinLocation(job) }
        Log.d("Main", "success: ${response.success}")
        binding.tvUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        if (response.success == false) {
            binding.tvUpdate.text = "Error"
        } else {
            binding.tvUpdate.text = "Moved!!"
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("Main", "IOException: You may not have an internet connection - ${e.message}")
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        Log.e("Main", "HttpException: Unexpected response - ${e.message}")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Main", "Error: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

I hope this can resolve your problems.

Comment: So I added this to both the runMoveCommand and the makeAPIRequest functions, so it says:


It gives me a ``Unresolved reference: withContext``` and ```Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body```

Not sure where to go from there?

Comment: Did you add the import of withContext() function?

Comment: I've done that (added ```withContext``` to the import section) and this builds now, but it didn't fix anything...

The makeAPIRequest function gets hit first, and the data comes down like before, but I still get ```Error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.``` on the ```binding.tvMoveLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);``` command.

The button disappears (which always worked) but the other field that should disappear is still there.

The other original issue is still there as well, as nothing reappears in the else section of the code.